# Событие на scroll, когда тот в самом низу страницы, учитывая что контент из-за которого появляется scroll динамический

Tags: javascript, события, dom, прокрутка, fetch

На сайт в DOM приходят только header и footer, main подгружается из JSON с помощью fetch.

Нужно осуществить подгрузку партии новостей из JSON тем же fetch, **когда scroll окажется в самом низу страницы**. Логика подгрузки уже готова, но повесить event на scroll (когда тот в самом низу) не выходит. Событие происходит при первом же скролле, причем не важно вверх или вниз...

Происходит это на сколько я понял из-за того, что эти посты отсутсвуют в DOM, так как загрузились из JSON и появились динамически. И для JS эта страница все так же "пустая". При клике на заголовок (динамически созданной карточки) с помощью e.target удается открыть новость, но как быть с scroll?

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let category = categoryNames();
  if(document.documentElement.scrollTop == document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) {
  fetchJson1(category); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let category = categoryNames();
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop == document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) {
        fetchJson1(category);
    } 
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]